# Library project showing wrong modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

I have two projects side by side

1. A library containing two modules - a custom view and a sample application
2. A LibGdx application with several modules, dependent on the library project

The problem is, when I open the library project in Android Studio it shows all of the modules from the LibGdx project as well as it's own two. This means I cannot even build the sample application because the run configuration only allows the 'android' module of the LibGdx project to be selected. (Meaning I can only use classes from the android module's manifest)

I assume the problem must be something to do with the LibGdx generated gradle files but I can't find the issue.

**Library project *settings.gradle***

```
include ':customview', ':customviewtestapp'
```

**Library project; root *build.gradle***

```
buildscript {
    repositories { ... }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects { repositories { ... } }

task clean(type: Delete) { delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

**Library project; customview module *build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    ....
    buildTypes {
        release ...
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ... //appcompat stuff
}
```

**LibGdx project *settings.gradle***

```
include ':android', ':core', 'textfieldboxes', 'customview'
project(":textfieldboxes").projectDir = file("../TextFieldBoxes/textfieldboxes")
project(":customview").projectDir = file("../CustomView/customview")
```

**LibGdx project; root *build.gradle***

```
buildscript {
    repositories { ... }
    dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1' }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "idea"
    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "MyApp"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.8'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.3'
        ...
    }

    repositories { ... }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"
    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        ... //Gdx Natives
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        ... //only Gdx dependencies
    }
}
```

**LibGdx project; android module *build.gradle***

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion 27
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        implementation project(':textfieldboxes')
        implementation project(':customview')
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    }
}

task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs() //var othersious
    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        ... //various others
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.my.app/com.my.app.AndroidLauncher'
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The project roots are both in the 'StudioProjects' directory under my user, but in separate subdirectories and I have at some points had both projects open in separate IDE windows

Comment: How is the library project even aware of your libGDX project, or of libGDX at all?

Comment: Well... that's the question

Comment: I would start with deleting all the .iml files from the library project and reopening it.

Comment: Haven't tried that yet so will give it a go. But any suggestions to stop it happening again if it works?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how the library project could become aware of other projects on its own.